# IOS: Char* array giving different ASCII value

Tags: ios, char

```
void UPDevice::echoCommand() {
    char* message = new char[32];
        UPMessageMarshallerNamespace::prepareMessage(message, STR_SIZE_32, "Echo");
}

void UPMessageMarshallerNamespace::prepareMessage(char* message, size_t messageLength, const char* payload) {
    if (messageLength > (strlen(payload) + 5)) {
        message[0] = 0xAA;
    printf("message1 %s",message);   
        message[1] = 101;
    printf("message2 %s",message);        

    } else {
        UP_MESSAGE_MARSHALLER_THROW(CRS("small buffer, can not prepare message"));
    }
}
```

on calling the echoCommand() method I am getting below o/p:
message1 TM(Trade mark sign)
message2 e

while ASCII value of 0xAA is TM sign. then why such o/p. Please any idea.

Comment: 0xAA is 170 in decimal. I don't get you very much .

Comment: @KudoCC you are right. This is 170. In ASCII table correspondance sign is ª but I am getting ™ (153 decimal value)

Comment: ASCII is 7-bit.  Beyond that you are talking character encodings like UTF-8 or ISO-8859-X.  In UTF-8 that character is decribed as [FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/aa/index.htm).  If you are shoving random non-printable characters into that buffer, you should **not** be printing it, you should be displaying its content in the form of a hex dump (with ASCII version on the right).

Comment: I have tried it on my device. `printf("%c", message[0])` is ª, but `printf("message1 %s",message)` gives ™. I'm confused too.

Comment: It's because `message` is not initialised so anything could be printed.  Bottom line is that it's not a printable string and therefore `printf()` or `NSLog()` should not be used to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0xAA", nil];
int size = [myArray count];
unsigned char testing[size];

unsigned holder;
```

//Either Try This

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]
     scanHexInt:&holder];
    testing[i] = holder; /* or check for errors before assigning */
    NSLog(@"%c",testing[i]);
}

//Or Try This

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    sscanf([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], "%x", &holder);
    testing[i] = holder; /* same thing */
    NSLog(@"%c",testing[i]);
}
```

This will give the out put ª